# webrtc: How can I share my screen to another user?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webrtc, jsx

I have a `webrtc` stream of two users. You need to make it possible to sharing screen to another user. I know I need to use `getDisplayMedia` for this. When I try to do this, I do screen sharing to myself. Apparently, you need to somehow *replace the video track*? But I don’t understand how...

```
export const LocalScreen: React.FC = () => {
    const socket = useContext(SocketContext);
    const [switchVideo, setSwitchVideo] = useState<boolean>(false);
    const [sharing, setSharing] = useState<boolean>(true);
    const userRef = useRef<HTMLVideoElement>(null);
    const guestRef = useRef<HTMLVideoElement>(null);
    const sharingUserRef = useRef<HTMLVideoElement>(null);
    const guestSharingRef = useRef<HTMLVideoElement>(null);
    const userStream = useRef<any>();
    const guestStream = useRef<any>();
    const peers: any = {};
    const pendingCandidates: any = {};

    const sendData = (data: {}) => {
        socket.emit('data', data);
    };
    const onAddTrack = (event: RTCTrackEvent) => {
        setSwitchVideo(true);
        const [MediaStream] = event.streams;
        if (guestRef.current) {
            guestRef.current.srcObject = MediaStream;
            guestStream.current = MediaStream;
        }
    };
    const onIceCandidate = (event: RTCPeerConnectionIceEvent) => {
        if (event.candidate) {
            sendData({
                type: 'candidate',
                candidate: event.candidate,
            });
        }
    };
    const createPeerConnection = () => {
        const pc = new RTCPeerConnection({
            iceServers: [],
        });
        pc.onicecandidate = onIceCandidate;
        pc.ontrack = onAddTrack;
        for (const track of userStream.current.getTracks()) {
            pc.addTrack(track, userStream.current);
        }
        return pc;
    };
    const setAndSendLocalDescription = (sid: string, sessionDescription: RTCSessionDescription) => {
        peers[sid].setLocalDescription(sessionDescription);
        sendData({sid, type: sessionDescription.type, sdp: sessionDescription.sdp});
    };
    const sendAnswer = (sid: string) => {
        peers[sid].createAnswer().then(
            (sdp: RTCSessionDescription) => setAndSendLocalDescription(sid, sdp),
            (error: {}) => {},
        );
    };
    const sendOffer = (sid: string) => {
        peers[sid].createOffer().then(
            (sdp: RTCSessionDescription) => setAndSendLocalDescription(sid, sdp),
            (error: {}) => {},
        );
    };
    const addPendingCandidates = (sid: string) => {
        if (sid in pendingCandidates) {
            pendingCandidates[sid].forEach((candidate: RTCIceCandidateInit | undefined) => {
                peers[sid].addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(candidate));
            });
        }
    };
    const handleSignalingData = (data: PeerData) => {
        const {sid} = data;
        switch (data.type) {
            case 'offer':
                peers[sid] = createPeerConnection();
                peers[sid].setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(data));
                sendAnswer(sid);
                addPendingCandidates(sid);
                break;
            case 'answer':
                peers[sid].setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(data));
                break;
            case 'candidate':
                if (sid in peers) {
                    peers[sid].addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(data.candidate));
                } else {
                    if (!(sid in pendingCandidates)) {
                        pendingCandidates[sid] = [];
                    }
                    pendingCandidates[sid].push(data.candidate);
                }
                break;
        }
    };

    const getMediaStream = () => {
        navigator.mediaDevices
            .getUserMedia({video: true, audio: false})
            .then(str => {
                if (userRef.current) userRef.current.srcObject = str;
                userStream.current = str;
                socket.connect();
            })
            .catch(error => {});
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        socket.on('data', (data: PeerData) => {
            handleSignalingData(data);
        });
        socket.on('ready', (msg: { sid: string }) => {
            peers[msg.sid] = createPeerConnection();
            sendOffer(msg.sid);
            addPendingCandidates(msg.sid);
        });
        socket.on('disconnect', (e: any) => {
            setSwitchVideo(false);
            if (userRef.current) userRef.current.srcObject = userStream.current;
        });
        getMediaStream();
    }, []);

    const screenSharing = async () => {
        if (sharing) {
            const MediaStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({
                video: {MediaSource: "screen"},
            });
            if (guestSharingRef.current) {
                guestSharingRef.current.srcObject = MediaStream;
            } else {
                if (sharingUserRef.current) {
                    sharingUserRef.current.srcObject = MediaStream;
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (guestRef.current) {
                guestRef.current.srcObject = guestStream.current;
            } else {
                if (userRef.current) {
                    userRef.current.srcObject = userStream.current;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    useBus(
        'webrtc/SCREEN_SHARING',
        () => {
            setSharing(!sharing)
            screenSharing().then()
        }, [sharing]
    )

    return (
        <div className={classes.container}>{sharing}
            {!switchVideo ? sharing ?
                (
                    <video
                        ref={userRef}
                        playsInline
                        autoPlay
                        width="100%"
                        height="100%"
                        className="userVideoStream"
                        muted
                        controls={false}
                    />
                ) :
                (
                    <video
                        ref={sharingUserRef}
                        playsInline
                        autoPlay
                        width="100%"
                        height="100%"
                        className="userVideoStream"
                        muted
                        controls={false}
                    />
                ) : sharing?
                (
                    <video
                        ref={guestRef}
                        playsInline
                        autoPlay
                        width="100%"
                        height="100%"
                        className="guestVideoStream"
                        controls={false}
                    />
                ) :
                (
                    <video
                        ref={guestSharingRef}
                        playsInline
                        autoPlay
                        width="100%"
                        height="100%"
                        className="guestVideoStream"
                        controls={false}
                    />
                )}
            <Controls stream={userStream}/>
        </div>
    );
};
```